# Generate a grey scale image from a numpy array and recover the same numpy array from the image

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to python and I am generating a grey scale image from a numpy array as follows:

My Array is: `[   7.09688331    9.17397351  -21.01224545 ...,   84.3304575   162.08131367 247.96525907]`

Array is of length 44100

```
#Generating Image
import scipy.misc as mi

from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.fromarray(sample.reshape(210,210), 'L')
print(img)
OUTPUT:<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=210x210 at 0xB5FD5304A8>

#Saving Image
filename='image1.png'

mi.imsave(filename, img)

#Now when I read the grey scale image I get different values from my original sample array? 


img1 = Image.open('image1.png')

array = np.reshape(img1, (1,np.product([210,210])))

print(array)
```

Output of array is: `[ 133  133  131 ...,  136  140  144]`

I want to recover the original array: `[   7.09688331    9.17397351  -21.01224545 ...,   84.3304575   162.08131367 247.96525907]`

How do I get back the original array when I read the grey scale image?

Comment: Your array contains `float` values, but an image is made of `int` values in the range of 0 - 254. You lose information converting from `float` to `int` and you can't get it back. At best, you would have to save the minimum and maximum values from your original array and then scale the image data to this range, which would give you approximately the same values, but with potentially less resolution than your original array.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Is it possible to normalize the array values based on your own min and max values and save as grey scale image. I tried the following   matplotlib.image.imsave(filename,img,vmin,vmax). However this saves the image as colored image.

Comment: If you add the keyword `cmap=cm.gray` to the `imsave` call, you will get a grayscale image, but I believe it will be saved as an RGB image. This should be fine for displaying it, but if you want a true grayscale image (L only), you'll have to convert the RGB image to a grayscale one.